# jQuery animted navigation how to collapse other elements on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I have a navigation menu animated with jquery, when i click on an element I want other menu voices to collapse. See the code to see my attempt to do it with no success. Also, I want the menu voices to collapse when I click on the same element i used to open it, or if I click on other main elements (orange), not when i click on children elements (white). Sorry for my english i hope it's clear. See jsfiddle to clarify. Uncomment the line to see my attempt.

http://jsfiddle.net/uwv0a6bL/

```
$('.main-nav li a').on('click', function(event) {

// $('.main-nav li a').not(this).parents().removeClass('open');

$(this).siblings('.submenu').toggleClass('open');    

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.main-nav li a').on('click', function(event) {

    // $('.main-nav li a').not(this).parents().removeClass('open');

    $(this).siblings('.submenu').toggleClass('open');   
    $(this).parent().siblings().children('.open').removeClass('open');

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uwv0a6bL/6/

Answer (score 0):

I think your function could look like this:

```
$('.main-nav li a').on('click', function(event) {

// $('.main-nav li a').not(this).parents().removeClass('open');
$('.submenu').removeClass('open');
$(this).siblings('.submenu').toggleClass('open');


});
```

here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uwv0a6bL/20/

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
$('.main-nav li a').on('click', function(event) {
    var submenu = $(this).siblings('.submenu');
    $('.submenu').not(submenu).removeClass('open');
    submenu.toggleClass('open');
});
```

Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/uwv0a6bL/21/) to see a working example.

Hope it's useful!